# AuthenticationException WebAPI / ASP MVC dotnet Core

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a solution with 2 projects using dotnet core

WebAPI Project -> REST API

MVC Project -> Connect to the API to get/post values

I have a core library class that has the Helper to connect the API:

```
public abstract class APIHelper
    {
        protected HttpClient ApiClient;

        public APIHelper()
        {
            InitializeClient();
        }

        private void InitializeClient()
        {
            ApiClient = new HttpClient();
            //ApiClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44333/api");
            ApiClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5001/api");
            ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept
                .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        }
    }
```

I have a class that inherits from that class and call the API:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Category>> Get()
{
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await ApiClient.GetAsync("api/Category"))
    {
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var readed = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Category>>(readed);
            return result;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }

    }
}
```

If I use Visual Studio and run the IIS server the API uses the `ApiClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44333/api");` It runs perfect and I can connect to the API using the Helper, and then call the helper class from the MVC project.

The problem is when I use the `dotnet run` command, the API runs at port 5001 and the MVC project runs on the port 5003, so I call the URI: `ApiClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5001/api");`.

When I do that way and try to open in my browser the https://localhost:5003 (MVC project) I ger the error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

System.Net.Security.SslStream.StartSendAuthResetSignal(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest, ExceptionDispatchInfo exception)
HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception.

System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsyncCore(Stream stream, SslClientAuthenticationOptions sslOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I tried using the http instead of https with the same result.

I tried using a different browser with the same result.

I tried it on Windows and Linux with the same result.

When I try it with Postman it gets the values so there is no problem with the WebPI project (I think so).

I do not know what to do.

Cheers.

Comment: Can you try to execute this command:  ‘dotnet dev-certs https --trust’ ?

Comment: Per this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: I used this and it worked https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#options

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have an issue on your SSL certificate and you can bypass this error as below I didn't try your code but it always works with me when adding the below code after initializing a new object from the HttpClient

```
// bypass bad SSL certificate errors
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
              delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate,
                       X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
              { return true; };
```

so your API helper should be like below

```
public abstract class APIHelper
{
    protected HttpClient ApiClient;

    public APIHelper()
    {
        InitializeClient();
    }

    private void InitializeClient()
    {
        ApiClient = new HttpClient();
        // bypass bad ssl certificate errors
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
              delegate (object s, X509Certificate certificate,
                       X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
              { return true; };
        //ApiClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44333/api");
        ApiClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:5001/api");
        ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        ApiClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept
            .Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }
}
```

Comment: can you try to connect to your API using RestSharp Client and you can see how to use it from this link (https://restsharp.dev/getting-started/#basic-usage )

Answer (score 0):

When you use visual studio to debug, it uses iisexpress as default startup option and has the port and SSL certificate configured for iisexpress.

Iisexpress will then talk to dotnet app either in process or reverse proxy based on the version of dotnet you use and the configuration in web.config.

When you run it using dotnet run, it uses kestrel and you need to setup port, SSL certificate and everything in code. Check the code in program.cs and startup.cs files.

One of it should have a call to usekestrel, which has additional options for kestrel that you can configure.

Comment: I used this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#options

Comment: That's not going to help you. You need to use this. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/web-host?view=aspnetcore-3.1#server-urls also check out this GitHub issue for more background https://github.com/aspnet/KestrelHttpServer/issues/639

Comment: And more info here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#endpoint-configuration